# Navigation from login screen to TabBar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

He everyone, I work on my project.
Below my storyboard and my old code.

I want to delete the Tabbar in the storyboard and created by code. I did it.

So if my tabBar is not set on any storyboard, how I can navigate from my login screen to my travels list screen without providing storyboard identifier?

Sorry for my English, I don't speak English very well.

```
func goToNextScreen() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToTravelListScreen", sender: userLoged)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.identifier == "GoToTravelListScreen" {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
            let listTravelVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainTabBar") as! UITabBarController
            listTravelVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(listTravelVC, animated: true, completion: {
                let navController = listTravelVC.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
                let vc = navController.topViewController as! TravelListViewController
                vc.userLoged = self.userLoged
            })
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0nsl.png)

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code and image you attached you need to put these lines

// Login screen controller

```
func goToNextScreen() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToTravelListScreen", sender: userLoged)
    }
```

put this code on login controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "GoToTravelListScreen" {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let listTravelVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TravelListViewController") as! TravelListViewController
    
listTravelVC.userLoged = self.userLoged
    self.navigation.pushviewcontroller(listTravelVC, animated: true)
}
}
```

from above code you will use the login controller navigation stack

Comment: Hi, @chanadboy, I want to remove segue. So can't use it.